Transparent image showing background and not logo in Blender
I have a transparent image in Blender that is only showing the background, not the actual subject I am trying to get it to show
The image shows up properly in paint:
But not in Blender:

You simply need to flip the green inputs in the mix shader node.

Ok, but that is exactly what @Spearhead is referring to with "switch between the order of the transparent and BSDF connections in the mix shader".

@taiyo sorry for not replying but I did want to say that was the correct solution

Instead of using the mix shader with alpha factor you can connect the image alpha directly to the 'Principled BSDF' alpha connection, and then directly connect the Principled BSDF to the output.
If you still want the mix shader with transparent BSDF you can switch between the order of the transparent and BSDF connections in the mix shader. or add a invert node to the alpha before connecting it to the mix shader factor.
